# how to set environment variable in config.php file in codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, environment-variables, config

I want to create an external file in codeigniter the file will have the database name, database user, base URL, and password. These variables can be set by environment variable or define a function.

Need to access these variables in config and database file

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) is a very flexible library. Once added to your project, you can create a file `.env` for your environment variables and then set it up like so in your `index.php` file:

```
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create('\\Path\\to\\.env');
$dotenv->load();
```

You can call then your environment variables anywhere using `getenv()`:

`$dbHost = getenv('DB_HOST');`